# Data structure/algorithm for merging similar items

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, computational-geometry

Requirements:

Given bunch of line segments in 2D plane I need to be able to merge all the ones that are similar or equal to each other.

For example if i was given two line segments `(0, 0) - (1, 1)` and `(1, 1) - (2, 2)`. Those two lines are connected and has the same slope. Thus I can just merge those two together into one line `(0, 0) - (2, 2)`

For line segments `(0, 0) - (1, 1)` and `(1.01, 1) - (2, 2)`. Even though their slopes are a bit different and they are not connected, its not that visible to human eyes so I would still merge those two into `(0, 0) - (2, 2)` in exchange for performance.

For line segments `(0, 0) - (1, 1)` and `(0.5, 0.5) - (0.6, 0.6)`. The later is just a segment of the former thus its safe to just remove the later and only preserve the former.

Obviously I can do this in brutal force way `O(n^2)` but that takes too long. Is there a good algorithm/data structure that could help to reduce the run time?

Attempts:
Range tree: It seems like a natural fit since it supports range query (lines with similar slope). However insert/delete are not supported.

R tree: R tree supports querying elements that are close by using a rectangle. Using this I could first find all lines that are within the bound box and filter out the ones with slope difference > epsilon or distance > epsilon2. However I can't find a good description on the implementation (search looks well documented but insert/delete are very vague)

B tree: B tree looks kind of promising but it seems like my use case is not the prime usage of it. Not sure if it would be the right way to go.

Comment: You can group segments by their slope (with some variation) and then do pairwise comparison separately in each group - it'll be not good only if all of them have the same slope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [projective duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)) with your favorite proximity structure (kd-tree, cover tree, etc.) to cluster the segments into groups that are nearly collinear. Then for each group you can use the standard sweep line algorithm to compute the union of intervals as a list of disjoint intervals.

To compute the projective coordinates for the line that contains `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`, we embed the endpoints in projective space as `(a, b, 1)` and `(c, d, 1)` and then compute the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). The thing with projective coordinates is that they're not unique. My naive suggestion would be to use the unit sphere in 3D as a covering space by normalizing with respect to the Euclidean norm and duplicating the point at its antipode.

In other words, we map `(a, b) - (c, d)` to `(x', y', z')` and `(-x', -y', -z')` where `(x, y, z) = (b - d, c - a, ad - bc)` and `x' = x/sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)` and `y' = y/sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)` and `z' = z/sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)`.

Comment: How should i do grouping if i have 3 line segments where line1 is nearly collinear to line2, line2 is nearly collinear to line3 but line1 is not nearly collinear to line3? If i group them as (1, 2) (3) and if line 1 and 2 are far away i will end up with 3 lines still. If line 2 and 3 are close then i should be grouping them as (1) (2, 3) so that i end up with 2 lines. Basically how should i handle lines close to the edge of each group. if i need to check near by groups then i need a way to update the tree (insert/delete) still.

Comment: @Steve Apply your favorite clustering algorithm, basically.

Answer (score 1):

Di you tried with a [Sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm)? You can find/count/detect [line segment intersections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection) which definitely sounds like your first step (detect if there's an intersection then check slopes). You could solve your problem in O((n+k)logn) (where k is the number of intersections) by using the [Bentley-Ottman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm). You basically sort your line segments and then swipe the plane with a line in that order, and stop on every crossing.

One more thing, you can calculate the slopes, then you can sort lexicographcally, first by slope, and then by x coordinate (or projecting to the line with such slope passing through the 0 point), then traverse the segments in that order. You can then do a simple "line sweep", just verify how far the segments are and merge. You can add some error to the slope, so you also put similar slopes in the same bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with mapping lines Ax+By+C=0 into (A,B,C) is that if two similar line segments with slightly different slopes are very far from the origin, different between C's become large, preventing the two segments from being clustered into one.

On the other hand, if the slopes of two line segments are very different, they can still be considered visually 'similar' if one of them is extremely short.

I doubt if any duality mapping->clustering->filtering methods would completely solve this problem. Consider the two following extreme cases:

- Line segment AB, an infinitely small line segment at A, an infinitely small line segment at B --> property of equality does not hold --> can never cluster line segments as-is --> one must first cluster the lines and then process the segments
- Line AB and CD has similar slope. If segment A'B' and C'D' are close to point of intersection, they are 'similar'; otherwise, they are not --> line segments cannot be processed after clustering

Hence the contradiction.

It seems to me that O(N^2) is probably the best you can get, based on the fact that for each line segment, the worst case would be to search among the entire bag of lines (or the remaining ones). Still, using some space partition techniques you can get better average-case complexity, assuming line segments are randomly distributed.